# what is mean by select * from ... where 1=condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen in sql procedures: `select * from table 1=1`

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.book_number   AS book_number, 
                b.book_title    AS b.nook_title, 
                o.order_summary AS order_summary, 
                otm.total_amt 
FROM   books b(nolock) 
       INNER JOIN books_detail bd (nolock) 
               ON b.b_id = bd.b_id 
       INNER JOIN order o(nolock) 
               ON o.author_id = b.author_id 
       INNER JOIN order_master otm(nolock) 
               ON otm.order_number = otm.order_number 
WHERE  b.status = 'AVAILABLE' 
       AND ( otm.cnt > 4 
              OR otm.total > 150 
              OR 1 = ( CASE 
                         WHEN @order = 'Any' THEN 0 
                         WHEN @order = 'devotional' THEN 1 
                         WHEN @order = 'investigation' THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END ) )
```

my question here is what is the use of

```
OR 1 = ( CASE 
                     WHEN @order = 'Any' THEN 0 
                     WHEN @order = 'devotional' THEN 1 
                     WHEN @order = 'investigation' THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END ) )
```

Comment: It's just filtering logic based on what the case statement returns.

Comment: tried it so many times but it was not letting me to post the question..

Comment: It is an overcomplicated way of doing this for sure. The whole piece you are unsure about could be simplified to OR @Order in ('devotional', 'investigation')

Comment: It means that only `devotional` and `investigation` wil be returned, not `any`

Comment: Also be careful splattering NOLOCK everywhere. It is not a magic go fast button. It has many very serious side affects that most people don't know about. An explanation can be found [here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/). Also omitting the WITH keyword for query hints has been deprecated so if you insist on using that hint at least use the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the logical process flow you will see that the result of the `case` expression is either a `1` or `0` and the `where` clause is checking to see if `1` is returned.

In this particular instance, the expression is equivalent to:

```
@order in ('devotional', 'investigation')
```